# Definition of routes with ASP.net and C #

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with the definition of routes with ASP.net and C #, using the GET verb. 
I get this URL,

```
http://123.45.67.89:39051/dev/point/save?name=125.25
```

I get this URL, where **point** changes according to where I want to search the data. The dev and save parameters are constant. The number of points is large, would need to make this could take any value with characters and numbers.
Modify the file WebApiConfig, trying it can take any value and did not work.

For example:

point12 
point23 
point24 
MzaB342 
Pozo123 
MzaE258

WebApiConfig

> ```
>            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); 
>            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
>            name: "DefaultApi",
>            routeTemplate: "dev/{points}/save",           
>            defaults: new { points= RouteParameter.Optional }
>            constraints: new { points= @"^[a-z]+$" }
>
>         );
> ```

How can I do this?

It is correct that I have to put `"^ [a-zA-Z0-9] + $"` to take qur numbers, but if problem persists tel sent a query a requirement

```
http://123.45.67.89:39051/dev/values/save?name=125.25
```

Works fine.
If I want to consult:

```
http://123.45.67.89:39051/dev/point12/save?name=125.25
```

I get a 404 error, because there is no route point12, these are name within a database, and there are a large amount, could not generate a route for each of them, have to redirect them to one and then to decode this route and assign the value.
Or what I get after `http://123.45.67.89:39051/dev/xxyyzz121/save` take it correctly, I separate the information from the URL, which allows me to control the request for each point, using data binding or Parse Query.
I can not change the way I get the URL, that comes from another system.

Try to test the solution to put the path and when I enter the class, have an error in ActionResult, you need to load System.Web.Mvc, as I am using WebAPI without MVC, can not find it, if it gives me errors added in WebAPI other classes.
As could be done to define default routes.

**Web.Api.Config Code:**

```
namespace WebApp_dev
{
     public static class WebApiConfig
     {
         public static void Register (HttpConfiguration config)
         {
             // Configuration API and Web services

             // Web API routes
             config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes ();

             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute (
                 name: "DefaultApi"
                 routeTemplate "dev / {controller} / {id}",
                 defaults: new {controller = "values", id = RouteParameter.Optional,},
                 constraints: new {controller = @ "^ [a-zA-Z0-9] + $"}
             );
         }
     }
}
```

**ValuesController.cs Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApp_dev.Controllers
{
     public class ValuesController: ApiController
     {
         // GET api / values
         public IEnumerable <string> Get ()
         {
             return new string [] {"value1", "value2"};
         }

         // GET api / values ​​/ 5
         public string Get (int id)
         {
             return "value";
         }

         // POST api / values
         public void Post ([FromBody] string value)
         {
         }

         // PUT api / values ​​/ 5
         public void Put (int id, [FromBody] string value)
         {
         }

         // DELETE api / values ​​/ 5
         public void Delete (int id)
         {
         }
     }
}
```

No, the name of the route changes, they are values​​, the URL that can reach between muchs are:

```
/dev/nombre1/save?name1=123.56
```

or

```
/dev/point123/save?name12=12
```

or

```
/dev/pozo12/save?value1=13
```

or

```
/dev/mbz134/save?costo2=13
```

or

```
/dev/patag235/save?name8=13
```

What changes is *name1, point123, pozo12, mbz134* etc. The amount is large, are stored in a database, and according to that comes, it is the search is done and the response sent.
The beginning of the URL **/dev** and end **/save?** It stays constant , what is after the **save?** (*name1, name12, value1, costo2, name8*) are the parameters that change and references also: *name1, point123, pozo12, mbz134* etc, which also change.

**Function properly, very good response.**

One more question I need to separate a variable point name for which I access the data, for example:

```
http://123.45.67.89:8090/dev/nombre1/save?name1=12.56&di2=1&an1=5
```

stored in a variable (**nombre_pto =**), the value entered: ***name1***

```
http://123.45.67.89:8090/dev/patag235/save?name1=3.56&name2=2.36&val4=5
```

stored in a variable (**nombre_pto =**), the value entered: ***patag235***

```
http://123.45.67.89:8090/dev/mza341/save?name1=123.56&pos2=23.36
```

stored in a variable (**nombre_pto =**), the value entered: ***mza341***

This will need to search the database and filter the information according to the parameters.

**From already thank you very much**

I could solve.

```
  string url_completa = Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath;
  // Busco el nombre del punto de medicion-----------
  int _indexPto = url_completa.IndexOf("/dev/");
  url_completa=url_completa.Remove(0, (_indexPto + 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex in your constraint could be "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED according to changes that were done in question description.**

To handle such urls you should:

1. Register wildcard route in WebApiConfig:

   ```
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "dev/{point}/save",
         defaults: new { controller = "Values", action = "Save" },
         constraints: new { point = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" }
     );
   ```
2. Write your controller to process this route:

   ```
   public class ValuesController : ApiController
   {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Save(string point)
        {
            // in point variable you will get part between /dev and /save
            // for /dev/point/save?name=125.25 url it will be "point"

            // get parameters that follow by ? mark in url
            var queryParams = GetQueryParams(Request);

            // loop through all of them
            foreach (var pair in queryParams)
            {
               string paramName = pair.Key;  // for /dev/point/save?name=125.25 will be "name"
               string paramvalue = queryParams[pair.Key]; // for /dev/point/save?name=125.25 will be 125.25
            }

            return "some value";
         }

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetQueryParams(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            return request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                         .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value,
                              StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
   }
   ```

Other urls are also fit this controller and this action.

Hope that finally it is what you were asking for.

Comment: Try to test the solution to put the path and when I enter the class have an error in ActionResult, you need to load System.Web.Mvc, as I am using WebAPI without MVC, can not find it, if it gives me errors added in WebAPI other classes.

Comment: Do you have one controller to process all request or controller per point? I assume that your ValuesController should handle requests for any point, so handle /dev/values/save?name=125.25 and /dev/values/point12?name=125.25 etc. Is it correct?

Comment: No, the name of the route changes, they are values​​, the URL that can reach between muchs are:
/dev/point123/save?name12=12;
/dev/pozo12/save?value1=13;
/dev/mbz134/save?costo2=13;
/dev/patag235/save?name8=13;